# How can I inject and use this javascript library (web3) with JavascriptCore

Tags: javascript, swift, ethereum, web3js, javascriptcore

I have been trying to use the [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) library with JavascriptCore in Swift. A web3 instance is created by running

`var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("[the provider im using]"))`

This is the code I am trying to do this in Swift with:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "web3", withExtension: "js"){
     let lib = try! String(contentsOfFile: url.path)
     let jsvirtualmachine = JSVirtualMachine()
     let context = JSContext(virtualMachine: jsvirtualmachine)
     context.evaluateScript(lib)

     let web3 = context.evaluateScript("var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('[myprovider]')")
     let fn = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("web3")
     let fn1 = fn?.construct(withArguments: [])
     let latestBlockNumber = context.evaluateScript("web3.eth.blockNumber")
     print(latestBlockNumber)
}
```

I have tried printing out latestBlockNumber, web3, fn, and fn1 and all of them return undefined

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you success with this try?

Answer (score 4):

The `web3.js` library has dependencies on [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/) and [crypto-js.js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) (See [dependencies here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/bower.json)). You will need to add these two JS libs to the bundle and load them in a similar way, e.g.

```
do {
    let bigNumberJS = try String(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "bignumber.min", withExtension: "js")!, encoding: .utf8)
    let cryptoJS = try String(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "crypto-js", withExtension: "js")!, encoding: .utf8)
    let web3JS = try String(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "web3-light.min", withExtension: "js")!, encoding: .utf8)
    context.evaluateScript(bigNumberJS)
    context.evaluateScript(cryptoJS)
    context.evaluateScript(web3JS)
    context.evaluateScript("var Web3 = require('web3'); var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));")
    if let version = context.evaluateScript("web3.version.api") {
        print("Web3 version is \(version)")
    }
}
catch {
    print("An error occurred")
}
```

Comment: hi, so unlike bignumber, crypto-js has multiple files. How to handle that?

Comment: Each of their releases contains a `crypto-js.js` which contains everything in one file. Try downloading the zip file of the latest release. https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/releases/tag/3.1.9-1